# Entire function of finite order having a deficient value

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

**Motivation**: We know that deficient values of an entire function $f$ are important because there is a connection with the  singular values of $f$ and hence a connection with the Fatou set of $f$.

There are some sufficient conditions for an entire function has a finite deficient value e.g., if the order $\rho$ of an entire function $f$ is such that $2<\rho<+\infty$ with all but finitely many zeros of $f$ are real, then $0$ is a deficient value of $f$.

**Question**: Is there any sufficient condition for an entire function of finite order 1 to have a finite deficient value?

In particular, does the function $f(z)=e^z+P(z)$ where $P(z)$ is a complex polynomial have a finite deficient value ?

**Target**: If I can show that $e^z+P(z)$ has a finite deficient value then all the Fatou components are simply connected.